# Change boolean that is in another class C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to change a public Boolean from another class to true or false if the button is pressed:

Settings class inside a folder called Data:

```
public class Settings
{
    [JsonProperty("songVolume")]
    public string SongVolume { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("repeatTrack")]
    public bool RepeatTrack { get; set; }
}
```

Button in the main window that will toggle Boolean true or false:

```
private void Loop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Loop.Content.ToString() == "\uE8ED")
    {
        //toggle boolean true here        
        Loop.Content = "\uE8EE";
    }
    else if (Loop.Content.ToString() == "\uE8EE")
    {
        //toggle boolean false here        
        Loop.Content = "\uE8ED";
    }
}
```

My save settings function:

```
public void SaveSettings()
{
    using (var StreamWriter = new StreamWriter($"{Environment.CurrentDirectory}\\utils\\Settings.json"))
    {
        Data.Settings settings = new Data.Settings
        {
            Volume = VolumeSlider.Value.ToString()
        };
        string formattedjson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(settings, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
        StreamWriter.Write(formattedjson);
        //var stuffString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(settings);
        //File.WriteAllText(@".\utils\Settings.json", stuffString);
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean you want to change the `RepeatTrack` property from `Loop_Click`? Then the class where `Loop_Click` is must have access to an instance of `Settings`. If that was named`settings` the code would be `settings.RepeatTrack = true;` (or `false`).

Comment: Yes, that it what I meant